# how to cleanly stop goroutines internally on error

Tags: go, exception, error-handling, tcp, goroutine

All,

I'm writing a program involving tcp traffic that has several points of failure, and
I'd like to be able to exit out of a goroutine smoothly in an error condition without incurring coding overhead.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
func main() {

    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+ CONN_PORT)

    for {                                                                                                                                                                              
        // Listen for an incoming connection.                                                                                                                                   
        conn, err := l.Accept()                                                                                                                                                        
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())                                                                                                                                  
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        done_flag := make(chan bool, 1)

        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.                                                                                                                                      
        go func() { 
            conn.Write([]byte("string1\n"))
            conn.Write([]byte("string2\n"))
            ...
        }()
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to avoid is the following code with the connection statements, where I wrap the code in error handling inside the goroutine (something like the following):

```
    go func() {
        if (_err := _send_ack(conn, "string1\n"); _err != nil {
            done_flag <- true
        }
        if (_err := _send_ack(conn, "string2\n"); _err != nil {
            done_flag <- true
        }
    }()
```

Instead, if there was a connection issue, I'd rather short circuit the whole thing and just exit the goroutine with an error right then and there - and I'd rather not have to worry about how I structure the code. I could perhaps, further wrap _send_ack and send the channel as a function parameter - but that gets iffy if the program gets to be highly hierarchical. For example, I might have a goroutine composed of several funcs, each of which handles a different tcp conversation - and I don't want to litter my subroutines with an extra channel parameter to propogate the channel up and down the call stack just in case I have to set a done flag. Plus there is the question of what happens to the goroutine after the done flag is being set and how to handle it in the caller.

If I was working in python, or perl, or C++, i'd throw an exception which has attached to it a stack trace where the error occurred and then process this error in the caller. But since golang doesn't have exceptions, I was hoping for a way to just stop the goroutine cold without actually exiting the main program - ie: set a channel to have the relevant error and then just stop execution at that point.

I see the panic function, but i'm not sure of the side effects of this. Can you panic() out of a goroutine without affecting the main program, or is there a way to intelligently short-circuit a goroutine without side effects, perhaps returning back something akin to an exception, with stack trace and error? Or what is the suggested way to cleanly error handle a hierarchical program like this?

Thanks much for any help - I'm new to golang and it probably shows.

Ed

Comment: Use `context.Context`, or use a channel and close the channel in case of error.

Comment: Burak - ok so you are suggesting passing around a context in the form of a channel and keeping state information around for it, and then closing the channel.

Comment: Not exactly. Usually `context.Context` is used for this purpose, and in case of an error, context is canceled so any goroutine sharing the same context can detect cancellation. This also allows passing around additional information with context. If however all you care about is cancellation, you can pass a channel and close it when an error happens  so all goroutines can detect cancellation. You have to check the channel every so often in all goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

golang suggests using explicit error instead of using implicit exception.

```golang
// for code simplicity
func doSendACKImpl(conn net.Conn) error {
    if err := _send_ack(conn, "string1\n"); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := _send_ack(conn, "string2\n"); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+ CONN_PORT)

    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        // can change to self defined ResponseType, here use error for demo
        workRes := make(chan error, 1)
        go func() {
            // return write back to channel
            workRes <- doSendACKImpl(conn)
        }()

        select {
        // read result back
        case resError := <-workRes:
            fmt.Printf("meet error %s", resError)
        }
    }
}
```

for more concurrent ability, use more channel buffer size, and move the processing result handler into another goroutine

```
func main() {
    l, _ := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)

    // more result buffer size
    const workSize int = 100

    // can change to self defined ResponseType, here use error for demo
    workResBuffer := make(chan error, workSize)

    // goroutine collect result
    go func() {
        // get all result from worker responses
        for resError := range workResBuffer {
            fmt.Printf("meet error %s", resError)
        }
    }()

    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        // TODO: limit the goroutine number
        go func() {
            // return write back to channel
            workResBuffer <- doSendACKImpl(conn)
        }()
    }
}
```